# Return one record per month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I haven't figured out how to group by date to get one 1 record per month this is my query:

```
select Date, weight 
  from Usrs 
 where usr = b 
 order by month
```

Which returns:

```
user b
date        weight
15/03/2017  18
15/03/2017  14
19/02/2017  19
18/03/2017  9
22/04/2017  24
30/04/2017  33
01/05/2017  15
03/05/2017  30
```

but I only need the last record of each month so what I want it will be like this

```
date        weight
15/03/2017  18
19/02/2017  19
18/03/2017  9
30/04/2017  33
03/05/2017  30
```

Any ideas how could I achieve my goal?

Comment: You have two rows for `15/03/2017` how do you know which is the last one?  If you only have a date, then how can you tell which is the last one?

Comment: Is this sql server or mysql?  These are not the same databases.

Comment: I was thinking using a row number funtion, but is not working yet

Comment: is SQL Server but I have a similiar problem on Mysql

Comment: One result row per month? Then why do I see both 2017-03-15 and 2017-03-18 in your result?

Comment: Sorry I copied by mistake

Comment: You're looking for a top / first result of a `group by`:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to number the records per month and stay with the last dates.

```
select date, weight
from
(
  select 
    date, weight, 
    row_number() over (partition by year(date), month(date) order by date desc) as rn
  from Usrs 
  where usr = 'b'
) numbered
where rn = 1
order by date;
```

This is standard SQL and works in SQL Server. It does not work in MySQL, though, as MySQL doesn't feature window functions such as `ROW_NUMBER`. You can emulate `ROW_NUMBER` in MySQL by using variables. Look it up; you will find many answers on this on SO.

Another option is to select the max dates per month and then select the according records:

```
select date, weight
from usrs
where usr = 'b'
and date in
(
  select max(date)
  from usrs
  where usr = 'b'
  group by year(date), month(date)
);
```

This again is standard SQL and works in both SQL Server and MySQL. Here the table has to be read twice, so the `ROW_NUMBER` method is usually the preferred one.